# Conway big picture for congruence subgroups of $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, lattices, arithmetic-groups

I saw in Conway’s paper *"[Understanding groups like $\Gamma_0(N)$](https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110893106.327)"* that the so-called Big Picture can give simple interpretations for important objects in number theory, such as Hecke operators and the normalizer of $\Gamma_0(N)$ (in essence Atkin–Lehner operators).

I am interested in understanding similar congruence subgroups in higher rank, e.g. the subgroups $\Gamma_0(N)$ of $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$ given by matrices with the last row of the form $(0, 0, *) \mod p$.
The question would then be if there are any references or folklore knowledge on this. Is there any intuition that the ideas in Conway's paper should work in this higher dimensional case (so that they still give interpretations for Hecke operators, normalizers etc.)?

Comment: FYI, I looked up this paper on MathSciNet, and I didn't see any papers about arithmetic groups in higher rank that refer to Conway's paper.  Thus my guess is that you won't find too much in the way of references.